# How to zip multiple files through tcl script in Linux box?

Tags: tcl

I have set of code in tcl where I'm trying to achieve to zip the files but I'm getting below error

```
zip warning: name not matched: a_1.txt a_2.txt a_3.txt a_4.txt
```

On other hand I'm doing same thing from command prompt I'm able to execute successfully.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh

set outdir /usr/test/
set out_files abc.10X
array set g_config { ZIP /usr/bin/zip }
set files "a_1.txt a_2.txt a_3.txt a_4.txt"

foreach inp_file $files {
    append zipfiles "$inp_file "
} 
exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files zipfiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl really cares about the boundaries between words, and doesn't split things up unless asked to. This is good as it means that things like filenames with spaces in don't confuse it, but in this case it causes you some problems.

To ask it to split the list up, precede the read of the word from the variable with `{*}`:

```
exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files {*}$files
```

This is ***instead of*** this:

```
exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files $files
# Won't work; uses "strange" filename
```

or this:

```
exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files zipfiles
# Won't work; uses filename that is the literal "zipfiles"
# You have to use $ when you want to read from a variable and pass the value to a command.
```

---

Got a *very* old version of Tcl where `{*}` doesn't work? Upgrade to 8.5 or 8.6! Or at least use this:

```
eval {exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files} $files
```

(You need the braces there in case you put a space in `outdir`…)

Comment: Fellow I have one question Is it possible I can zip single file through this command exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files {*}$files